# Automounting with fstab not working on Ubuntu guest VM on OSX host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, fstab

I've been setting up a new development environment using VirtualBox so I can sandbox my services and such in their own VM. It's an Ubuntu-based VM, which loads as a headless instance that I SSH into from the host machine.

What I'd like to do is store all my project files on the host machine and then share them with the guest VM. I can do this easily enough with the following command:

`sudo mount -t vboxsf <name> <target_path>`

This works perfectly. However, it's a bit of a pain to have to run that command every time I start the VM. It means I have to start it, ssh in, execute command and restart my various services which require access to the data stored on the host machine (postgresql, apache, mongo, etc...).

I figured using `fstab` would be the best route, so I went about adding the following entry to the list:

`# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

HostWWW /home/wilhelm/www       vboxsf`

Easy enough, right? Well, I save and exit, reboot the VM, SSH back in, navigate to the mount point for the shared folder and it's still empty. I do a quick `ls -lsa` and get nothing. So, I run the following command to see if it's actually been mounted:

`mount -v`

and I see the following line within the resulting list of mount points:

`HostWWW on /home/wilhelm/www type vboxsf (rw)`

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but this should tell me that it actually has been mounted with read/write access. Now, if I REmount the share again with the same command as above, everything works just fine.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here; how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Disable `Auto-mount` on the shared folder in VirtualBox Manager.
- Add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

  `HostWWW /home/wilhelm/www vboxsf defaults 0 0`

It will work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, buddy! I haven't had this issue for a while now. I've been using Vagrant for the past year and haven't had any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out this was easily resolved by adding that command to `/etc/rc.local`. Would still like to get `fstab` properly working.